# Объявление и инициализация контейнеров Java

Tags: java, hashset

Пишу что-то типа калькулятор. Нужно создать контейнер, хранящий операции (+, -, *, etc).
Думаю хранить их в `static final HashSet`, но не могу понять как в классе создать и сразу инициализировать контейнер. В `C++` воспользовался бы списком инициализации, но, на сколько я понял, в `Java` их нет.
Как это сделать?

Comment: а почему не использовать просто массив?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman При разборе входной строки поиск по массиву займет значительно больше времени, чем по множеству

Comment: откуда у вас такие данные? вы сделали benchmark?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Это очевидно

Comment: вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией - это очевидно. в вашем случае вполне вероятна обратная ситуация - так как данных мало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете проинициализировать этот объект используя:

- static блок

  ```
  private static final Set<String> set;
  static {
      set = new HashSet<>();
  }
  ```
- static метод

  ```
  private static final Set<String> set = init();

  private static Set<String> init() {
      return new HashSet<>();
  }
  ```
- двойные {}

  ```
  private static final Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>() {{
      add("+");
  }};
  ```

Comment: Замечу, что в третьем случае создается анонимный наследник от `HashSet`, и *в редких случаях* это может привести к нежелательному поведению.